# How to find libavcodec to build VLC (with AFL fuzz)?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, vlc

I'm running a Ubuntu 64-bit system in a VM. I wanted to fuzz the VLC media player, so I grabbed the tar file, and built the dependencies and tried configuring it using this line:

```
./configure CC="afl-gcc" CXX="afl-g++" --disable-shared; make
```

However, this runs into an error:

> requested libavcodec >= 57.37.100 but version of libavcodec is 56.60.100

Is there a workaround for this, other than building a new one from contrib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a number of options:

- rebuild a recent `ffmpeg` source package to get `libavcodec57` & co.;
- upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10 which has `libavcodec57`;
- follow the VLC package approach, which is to embed the appropriate version of `fmmpeg` and use that instead.

The latter approach is the one I'd recommend; to get started:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts
dget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vlc/vlc_2.2.4-8.dsc
cd vlc-2.2.4
CC=afl-gcc CXX=afl-g++ dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

This will tell you which other packages you need to install (if any). If you don't want to use `dpkg-buildpackage`, see at least [`debian/rules`](https://salsa.debian.org/multimedia-team/vlc/blob/master/debian/rules) for the relevant configuration options.

Comment: @StephenKitt I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.10 (Desktop) and applied all pending updates. But if I try to compile VLC I still get the same error. So what have you done to get libavcoded57 integrated in v16.10?

Comment: @PeterCo I didn't do anything, it's [in universe](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg) (so perhaps you need to enable the universe repository).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you.
Finally i found it's wrong version of vlc source code.
Take care of your git checkout command. Is it really on vlc version 2.2.0?
In my case, i checkout with default (the latest) version and it is 3.0.0 which is still under developing and depends on libavcodec 57.

Answer (score -2):

rebuild a recent ffmpeg source package to get libavcodec57 and so forth

this is probably the fastest way (see below) to get going. apt install nasm yasm if needed.

Comment: this seems to be a sloppy abbreviation of [Stephen's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322825/117549), with an afterthought "apt install nasm yasm". Could you elaborate on how your answer is different from Stephen's?

Comment: it shows the imho the fastest way, which many people want to opt for. Btw, even faster is to build vlc-nightly-git from AUR in Mamjaro Distro, 100% hassle free.

Comment: keep in mind that people will read this if they have related questions too, some some will find it useful, even when the original Q. is touched lightly only.